# Passing values from select box to external main.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with pretty-dropdowns and add-to-cart-interaction plugins.
pretty-dropdowns takes the default select box and makes it pretty, but it does that by assigning ul and li tags by itself, including their ids (or maybe I'm wrong?)

the add-to-cart-interaction is, well, as you might have guessed it - a plugin that is written in CSS and JS that adds to cart.

I want to get the values from the pretty select boxes and add them to cart.

I am unable to do it since I do not know how to get the value from the pretty select box.
When I tried to retrieve from the "OG" select box it just gave me the default value that says: "Please Select".

Here is the code:

HTML (of the regular select boxes - before they get pretty):

```
    <select name="parent_selection" autocomplete="off" id="parent_selection">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="universal">Universal Premium</option>
        <option value="adapter">Scheibenwischer Adapters</option>
        <option value="excellence">Excellence Premium</option>
        <option value="hybrid">Hybrid Symbio</option>
        <option value="revf">Re-View F</option>
        <option value="revg">Re-View G</option>

    </select>

    <select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
    <option value="">Choose Wiper Line First</option>
    </select>
    <input id="mengescheiben" type="number" maxlength="4" max="4" placeholder="Menge" style="text-align: center; position: relative; width: 5em; height:auto;; font: normal 18px Calibri, sans-serif; font-size:30px;" />
    <p id="note" style="color: red"></p>
    <p id="note-special" style="color: red"></p>
```

HTML of the add to cart plugin(it doesn't really matter since it is creating a small interactive cart in the bottom right:

```
 <div class="cd-cart cd-cart--empty js-cd-cart">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-cart__trigger text-replace">
        <ul class="cd-cart__count"> <!-- cart items count -->
            <li>0</li>
            <li>0</li>
        </ul> <!-- .cd-cart__count -->
    </a>

    <div class="cd-cart__content">
        <div class="cd-cart__layout">
            <header class="cd-cart__header">
                <h2>Cart</h2>
                <span class="cd-cart__undo">Item removed. <a href="#0">Undo</a></span>
            </header>

            <div class="cd-cart__body">
                <ul>
                    <!-- products added to the cart will be inserted here using JavaScript -->
                </ul>
            </div>

            <footer class="cd-cart__footer">
                <a href="#0" class="cd-cart__checkout">
          <em>Checkout - $<span>0</span>
            <svg class="icon icon--sm" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g fill="none" stroke="currentColor"><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x1="3" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"/><polyline stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" points="15,6 21,12 15,18 "/></g>
            </svg>
          </em>
        </a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- .cd-cart__content -->
</div> <!-- cd-cart -->
```

and here comes the fun part. I will try to break down and explain as much as I can:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$parentDrop = $('#parent_selection').prettyDropdown({
classic: true, height: 80
});

});

</script>
```

This is where the pretty-dropdown gets initiated and puts some make up on my OG select box that was created earlier.

Continuing to where I create the lists for the select boxes:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
//let's create arrays
var excellence = [
    {display: "14″ 350mm", value: "14" }, 
    {display: "16″ 380mm", value: "16" }, 
    {display: "18″ 450mm", value: "18" },
    {display: "19″ 480mm", value: "19" }, 
    {display: "20″ 500mm", value: "20" }, 
    {display: "21″ 530mm", value: "21" },
    {display: "22″ 550mm", value: "22" }, 
    {display: "24″ 600mm", value: "24" }, 
    {display: "26″ 650mm", value: "26" },
    {display: "28″ 700mm", value: "28" }];

var hybrid = [
    {display: "14″ 350mm", value: "14" }, 
    {display: "16″ 380mm", value: "16" }, 
    {display: "18″ 450mm", value: "18" },
    {display: "19″ 480mm", value: "19" }, 
    {display: "20″ 500mm", value: "20" }, 
    {display: "21″ 530mm", value: "21" },
    {display: "22″ 550mm", value: "22" }, 
    {display: "24″ 600mm", value: "24" }, 
    {display: "26″ 650mm", value: "26" }];

var universal = [
    {display: "12″ 300mm", value: "12" },
    {display: "14″ 350mm", value: "14" }, 
    {display: "15″ 380mm", value: "15" }, 
    {display: "16″ 400mm", value: "16" },
    {display: "17″ 430mm", value: "17" }, 
    {display: "18″ 450mm", value: "18" }, 
    {display: "19″ 480mm", value: "19" },
    {display: "20″ 500mm", value: "20" }, 
    {display: "21″ 530mm", value: "21" }, 
    {display: "22″ 550mm", value: "22" },
    {display: "23″ 580mm", value: "23" },
    {display: "24″ 600mm", value: "24" },
    {display: "25″ 630mm", value: "25" },
    {display: "26″ 650mm", value: "26" },
    {display: "27″ 680mm", value: "27" },
    {display: "28″ 700mm", value: "28" },
    {display: "29″ 730mm", value: "29" },
    {display: "30″ 750mm", value: "30" },
    {display: "32″ 800mm", value: "32" }];

var adapter = [
    {display: "A", value: "A" },
    {display: "B1", value: "B1" }, 
    {display: "B2", value: "B2" }, 
    {display: "B3", value: "B3" },
    {display: "B4", value: "B4" }, 
    {display: "B5", value: "B5" }, 
    {display: "B7", value: "B7" },
    {display: "B8", value: "B8" }, 
    {display: "C", value: "C" }, 
    {display: "D", value: "D" },
    {display: "E", value: "E" },
    {display: "F", value: "F" },
    {display: "H", value: "H" }];

var revf = [
{display: "10″ 250mm", value: "10" },
{display: "11″ 280mm", value: "11" },
{display: "12″ 300mm", value: "12" },
{display: "13″ 330mm", value: "13" },
{display: "14″ 350mm", value: "14" },
{display: "15″ 380mm", value: "15" },
{display: "16″ 400mm", value: "16" },
{display: "17″ 430mm", value: "17" }];


var revg = [
{display: "9″ 230mm", value: "9" },
{display: "10″ 250mm", value: "10" },
{display: "11″ 280mm", value: "11" },
{display: "12″ 300mm", value: "12" },
{display: "13″ 330mm", value: "13" },
{display: "14″ 350mm", value: "14" },
{display: "15″ 380mm", value: "14" },
{display: "16″ 400mm", value: "16" }];
```

Moving on to the section where all the logic is (if user picks this - present THIS list, and on and on) and populating the 2 select boxes:

```
$parentDrop.change(function() {
$('#note-special').html("");
  $childDrop = $('#child_selection').prettyDropdown({
classic: true, height: 80
});
$childDrop.show();
    var $schparent = $(this).val(); //get option value from parent
        switch($schparent){ //using switch compare selected option and populate child
              case 'excellence':
                list(excellence);
                $('#note').html("* 1 STK.");
                break;
              case 'hybrid':
                list(hybrid);
                break;              
              case 'universal':
                list(universal);
                $('#note').html("* Auf jeden Wish Universal Premium Scheibenwischer ist ein A Adapter schon vormoniert");
                $('#note-special').html("* 1 STK.");
                break;
              case 'adapter':
                list(adapter);
                $('#note').html("* 1 STK.");
                break;
              case 'revf':
                list(revf);
                $('#note').html("* 1 STK.");
                break;
              case 'revg':
                list(revg);
                $('#note').html("* 1 STK.");
                break;  
            default: //default child option is blank
                $childDrop.html('""');
                $('#note').html("");
                $('#note-special').html("");
                $childDrop.hide();
                $('#mengescheiben').hide();     
                break;
           }
$parentDrop.refresh();
$childDrop.refresh();

//function to populate child select box
function list(array_list)
{
    $childDrop.html("Choose Wiper Line First"); //reset child options
    $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options 
        $childDrop.append("<option value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
    });
$childDrop.refresh();
$('#mengescheiben').show('slow');
}

});

});
```

And finally - the main.js of the add-to-cart plugin (FULL EXPLANATION AFTER THIS SECTION):

```
(function(){
  // Add to Cart Interaction - by CodyHouse.co
  var cart = document.getElementsByClassName('js-cd-cart');
  if(cart.length > 0) {
    var cartAddBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('js-cd-add-to-cart'),
        cartBody = cart[0].getElementsByClassName('cd-cart__body')[0],
        cartList = cartBody.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
        cartListItems = cartList.getElementsByClassName('cd-cart__product'),
        cartTotal = cart[0].getElementsByClassName('cd-cart__checkout')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0],
        cartCount = cart[0].getElementsByClassName('cd-cart__count')[0],
        cartCountItems = cartCount.getElementsByTagName('li'),
        cartUndo = cart[0].getElementsByClassName('cd-cart__undo')[0],
        productId = 0, //this is a placeholder -> use your real product ids instead
        cartTimeoutId = false,
        animatingQuantity = false;
        initCartEvents();


        function initCartEvents() {
            // add products to cart
            for(var i = 0; i < cartAddBtns.length; i++) {(function(i){
                cartAddBtns[i].addEventListener('click', addToCart);
            })(i);}

            // open/close cart
            cart[0].getElementsByClassName('cd-cart__trigger')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                toggleCart();
            });

            cart[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                if(event.target == cart[0]) { // close cart when clicking on bg layer
                    toggleCart(true);
                } else if (event.target.closest('.cd-cart__delete-item')) { // remove product from cart
                    event.preventDefault();
                    removeProduct(event.target.closest('.cd-cart__product'));
                }
            });

            // update product quantity inside cart
            cart[0].addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select') quickUpdateCart();
            });

            //reinsert product deleted from the cart
            cartUndo.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if(cartTimeoutId) clearInterval(cartTimeoutId);
                    // reinsert deleted product
                    var deletedProduct = cartList.getElementsByClassName('cd-cart__product--deleted')[0];
                    Util.addClass(deletedProduct, 'cd-cart__product--undo');
                    deletedProduct.addEventListener('animationend', function cb(){
                        deletedProduct.removeEventListener('animationend', cb);
                        Util.removeClass(deletedProduct, 'cd-cart__product--deleted cd-cart__product--undo');
                        deletedProduct.removeAttribute('style');
                        quickUpdateCart();
                    });
                    Util.removeClass(cartUndo, 'cd-cart__undo--visible');
                }
            });
        };

        function addToCart(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if(animatingQuantity) return;
            var cartIsEmpty = Util.hasClass(cart[0], 'cd-cart--empty');
            //update cart product list
            addProduct(this);
            //update number of items 
            updateCartCount(cartIsEmpty);
            //update total price
            updateCartTotal(this.getAttribute('data-price'), true);
            //show cart
            Util.removeClass(cart[0], 'cd-cart--empty');
        };

        function toggleCart(bool) { // toggle cart visibility
            var cartIsOpen = ( typeof bool === 'undefined' ) ? Util.hasClass(cart[0], 'cd-cart--open') : bool;

            if( cartIsOpen ) {
                Util.removeClass(cart[0], 'cd-cart--open');
                //reset undo
                if(cartTimeoutId) clearInterval(cartTimeoutId);
                Util.removeClass(cartUndo, 'cd-cart__undo--visible');
                removePreviousProduct(); // if a product was deleted, remove it definitively from the cart

                setTimeout(function(){
                    cartBody.scrollTop = 0;
                    //check if cart empty to hide it
                    if( Number(cartCountItems[0].innerText) == 0) Util.addClass(cart[0], 'cd-cart--empty');
                }, 500);
            } else {
                Util.addClass(cart[0], 'cd-cart--open');
            }
        };

        function addProduct(target) {
            // this is just a product placeholder
            // you should insert an item with the selected product info
            // replace productId, productName, price and url with your real product info
            // you should also check if the product was already in the cart -> if it is, just update the quantity
            productId = productId + 1;
            var productAdded = '<li class="cd-cart__product"><div class="cd-cart__image"><a href="#0"><img src="assets/img/product-preview.png" alt="placeholder"></a></div><div class="cd-cart__details"><h3 class="truncate"><a href="#0">Product Name</a></h3><span class="cd-cart__price">$25.99</span><div class="cd-cart__actions"><a href="#0" class="cd-cart__delete-item">Delete</a><div class="cd-cart__quantity"><label for="cd-product-'+ productId +'">Qty</label><span class="cd-cart__select"><select class="reset" id="cd-product-'+ productId +'" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option></select><svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 12 12"><polyline fill="none" stroke="currentColor" points="2,4 6,8 10,4 "/></svg></span></div></div></div></li>';
            cartList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', productAdded);
        };

        function removeProduct(product) {
            if(cartTimeoutId) clearInterval(cartTimeoutId);
            removePreviousProduct(); // prduct previously deleted -> definitively remove it from the cart

            var topPosition = product.offsetTop,
                productQuantity = Number(product.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value),
                productTotPrice = Number((product.getElementsByClassName('cd-cart__price')[0].innerText).replace('$', '')) * productQuantity;

            product.style.top = topPosition+'px';
            Util.addClass(product, 'cd-cart__product--deleted');

            //update items count + total price
            updateCartTotal(productTotPrice, false);
            updateCartCount(true, -productQuantity);
            Util.addClass(cartUndo, 'cd-cart__undo--visible');

            //wait 8sec before completely remove the item
            cartTimeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
                Util.removeClass(cartUndo, 'cd-cart__undo--visible');
                removePreviousProduct();
            }, 8000);
        };

        function removePreviousProduct() { // definitively removed a product from the cart (undo not possible anymore)
            var deletedProduct = cartList.getElementsByClassName('cd-cart__product--deleted');
            if(deletedProduct.length > 0 ) deletedProduct[0].remove();
        };

        function updateCartCount(emptyCart, quantity) {
            if( typeof quantity === 'undefined' ) {
                var actual = Number(cartCountItems[0].innerText) + 1;
                var next = actual + 1;

                if( emptyCart ) {
                    cartCountItems[0].innerText = actual;
                    cartCountItems[1].innerText = next;
                    animatingQuantity = false;
                } else {
                    Util.addClass(cartCount, 'cd-cart__count--update');

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        cartCountItems[0].innerText = actual;
                    }, 150);

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        Util.removeClass(cartCount, 'cd-cart__count--update');
                    }, 200);

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        cartCountItems[1].innerText = next;
                        animatingQuantity = false;
                    }, 230);
                }
            } else {
                var actual = Number(cartCountItems[0].innerText) + quantity;
                var next = actual + 1;

                cartCountItems[0].innerText = actual;
                cartCountItems[1].innerText = next;
                animatingQuantity = false;
            }
        };

        function updateCartTotal(price, bool) {
            cartTotal.innerText = bool ? (Number(cartTotal.innerText) + Number(price)).toFixed(2) : (Number(cartTotal.innerText) - Number(price)).toFixed(2);
        };

        function quickUpdateCart() {
            var quantity = 0;
            var price = 0;

            for(var i = 0; i < cartListItems.length; i++) {
                if( !Util.hasClass(cartListItems[i], 'cd-cart__product--deleted') ) {
                    var singleQuantity = Number(cartListItems[i].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value);
                    quantity = quantity + singleQuantity;
                    price = price + singleQuantity*Number((cartListItems[i].getElementsByClassName('cd-cart__price')[0].innerText).replace('$', ''));
                }
            }

            cartTotal.innerText = price.toFixed(2);
            cartCountItems[0].innerText = quantity;
            cartCountItems[1].innerText = quantity+1;
        };
  }
})();
```

You might be asking yourselves why I added the main.js of the plugin.
Well, a lot of changes need to be made into it to make it working.
I cannot figure out how to make it work though. Firstly, I tried playing with the variables, assuming that if I loaded "main.js" on my site, it will let me use the variables as if they were global (I am a beginner and I was so wrong).

After realizing it will not work, I tried adding all the code of the main.js under

```
$parentDrop.change(function() {
```

to have access to the schparent variable that gets the value from $(this).val() (the select box) which was previously stored in $parentDrop.

```
var $schparent = $(this).val(); //get option value from parent
```

It worked, partially.
I could add to cart the right product (by its name), but the plugin got buggy and did not open the cart sometimes. It even added the same thing twice or thrice which made me restore and begin from scratch.

This is how I stored the old selectbox and initiated the pretty-dropdown:

```
 $parentDrop = $('#parent_selection').prettyDropdown({ classic: true, height: 80 });
```

It is also written above.

It is required to parentDrop.refresh(); each time a value changes in the select box.

So from all of the above, could someone explain to me how to accomplish my goal? 
To sum it up, I just need a working way of getting the values from those pretty dropdowns so I could start manipulating the add to cart function.

Links to the plugins:
[pretty-dropdowns](https://github.com/thdoan/pretty-dropdowns)
[add-to-cart-interaction](https://github.com/CodyHouse/add-to-cart-interaction)